# React 18: Executing Code When Suspense Completes Promise

Tags: reactjs, react-suspense

I want to be able to make my own state change when when the return from `useTransition` completes.  That is, currently, in the example below, `isPending` toggles from true to false, but that's not enough. I want to be able to execute code on that change.

That is, in the example below, I would like to possible do something similar to what `useEffect` does, and have the code that is returned from the `startTransition` execute when the pending event changes, but that does not work.

Any other options?

```
onClick={() => {
          startTransition(() => {
            const nextUserId = getNextId(resource.userId);
            setResource(fetchProfileData(nextUserId));
            return () => { DO THIS CODE WHEN PENDING BECOMES FALSE }
          });
        }}
```

```
function App() {
  const [resource, setResource] = useState(initialResource);
  const [startTransition, isPending] = useTransition({
    timeoutMs: 3000
  });
  return (
    <>
      <button
        disabled={isPending}
        onClick={() => {
          startTransition(() => {
            const nextUserId = getNextId(resource.userId);
            setResource(fetchProfileData(nextUserId));
          });
        }}
      >
        Next
      </button>
      {isPending ? " Loading..." : null}
      <ProfilePage resource={resource} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: What do You mean by:  `but that does not work`?

Comment: I mean the DO THIS CODE never executes.

Answer (score 1):

It's is not possible within the `startTransition` call / `useTransition` config. You can use `useEffect/useLayoutEffect` to run some code after `resource` update.

```
useEffect/useLayoutEffect(() => {
    // some code after resource state update
}, [resource])
```